# c# как получить неизвестный количество атрибутов из Xml

Tags: c#, xml

День добрый,
Когда отправлю запрос получаю вот такого вида ответа:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response result="0">
    <check result="0">
        <extras PRV_TXN_ID="538659" disp1="text1" disp2="text2" disp3="text3"/>
    </check>
</response>
```

Мне надо вывести на консоль список `disp(с номером)`. Количество `disp` неизвестен и  зависит от запроса. На этом ответе 3 дисплея но до получение ответа я не знал сколько будет дисплеев. Как это узнать?

Парсер:

```
 public static XmlDocument postXMLData(string xml)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Requests.url);
            byte[] bytes;
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
            request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            request.Method = "POST";
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    var result = new XmlDocument();
                    result.LoadXml(responseText);
                    return result;
                }
            }

            throw new Exception("что то не так");
        }
```

Comment: Если не знаем  какое кол-во  атрибутов из XML надо получить, можно использовать метод Attributes объекта XmlElement, который возвращает коллекцию атрибутов элемента. Затем, можно перебрать все атрибуты в цикле и проверить, начинается ли имя атрибута с disp.

Comment: Лучше всего будет изменить схему xml, чтобы у элемента extras были не атрибуты, а вложенные елементы disp. Если это ваш сервис, измените схему. Или свяжитесь с авторами чужого сервиса, объясните им, как делать правильно.

Comment: @AleksandrFetisov а как проверить в цикле начинается ли имя атрибута с disp?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ответ получаем из сервиса большой компании вряд ли они для меня изменять схему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее решение.

Оно использует LINQ to XML.

Нет необходимости в каких-либо циклах.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<response result='0'>
            <check result='0'>
                <extras PRV_TXN_ID='538659' disp1='text1' disp2='text2' disp3='text3'/>
            </check>
        </response>");

    var attrs = xdoc.Descendants("extras")?
        .Attributes().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("disp"));
    
    Console.Write(attrs);
    Console.Write(attrs.Count());
}
```

**Результат**

```
disp1="text1" 
disp2="text2" 
disp3="text3" 

3
```

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: огромное Вам спасибо! Смотрите мой метод postXml работы с запросами написано на XmlDocument и как я могу вызвать XmlDocument на XDocument? Вызвать Load(postXml(xml)) пробовал не как

Comment: LINQ to XML доступен в .Net Framework с 2007 года. Желательно перейти на него. Пожалуйста, не забудьте пометить ответ как Ответ.

Comment: код который вы написали тут, тупо копировал и вставил, на консоль выдает ошибка `system.linq.enumerable+whereenumerableiterator`

Comment: Вам нужно использовать метод .Parse() для загрузки XML в виде текста.

Comment: именно ваш код содержит метод .Parse() и я просто копи пастил и такая ошибка

Comment: Возможно, отсутствует LINQ reference или использование LINQ namespaces.

Comment: `using System.Xml.Linq;` тоже подключен

Comment: Мой код работает и полностью протестирован.

Comment: можно ли делать тоже самое на XElement?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142954/discussion-between-john-paul-johns-and-yitzhak-khabinsky).

Comment: `<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />`

Comment: `XElement` тоже будет работать.

Comment: `using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;`

Comment: вообще без понятие, почему у меня вообще не работает неймспейси включил все как у вас